# Tracking personalization version views jExperience - Jahia Marketing Factory

Tags: jahia

I have a question about the personalization content functionality available on Jahia.

I would like to know if it was possible to know the number of displays for a personalization, for example I have content A and content B, and I want to know how many times content A was displayed for visitors?

This seems possible for optimization tests (A / B tests) but not for content customizations.

As an example here for optimization tests:
https://academy.jahia.com/documentation/enduser/mf/1.11/using-jexperience/managing-personalizations-and-optimization-tests/creating-optimization-tests-in-edit-mode#Interpreting_test_results but nothing for customizations . .

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly your question you can achieve that creating a goal to your personalization: https://academy.jahia.com/documentation/enduser/mf/1.11/using-jexperience/managing-and-monitoring-metrics/creating-and-viewing-goals

Then you can create a dashboard to track the performance of your personalization. In your case a goal type "Page Visit" should be what you are looking for.

Regards